# Does the Latin word for "garden" (hortus) also mean "vagina"?

Tags: word-usage, semantics, slang, homonyms

Dr. Alexander Kohut in [Arukh Completum (vol. 2 p. 314)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48230&st=&pgnum=319) claims that the Latin word *hortus* (and its Greek etymon), which means "garden" also refers to a woman's private parts (I'm assuming the vagina). The context in which he says this is rabbinic exegesis which explains the Hebrew word "garden" as referring to a woman. Kohut has been known to sometimes make things up, but other times he's right on the mark. So I was wondering if my colleagues here can either confirm or deny Kohut's claim.

Comment: As an aside, κῆπος is in no sense the etymon of *hortus*. Greek has a *cognate* of Latin *hortus* in χόρτος 'feeding place; fodder' (which is not used for the pudenda muliebria), but not an *etymon*; the Latin is not derived from the Greek.

Comment: These kinds of metaphors are quite common even in folklore songs in modern langauges. In Czech and Moravian folklore songs a garden can often mean the female crotch area or female virginity. Often young ladies protect their gardens, sometimes there is a flower inside that must not be picked by anyone. But often enough only the garden is mentioned.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава "lady garden" is a somewhat twee euphemism not infrequently made fun of in English-language comedy today

Comment: @Cairnarvon I don't see κῆπος mentioned in this question, only in cmw's answer which doesn't refer to it as an etymon. The rest of your comment is good, but I'm confused about the start of it, is there another comment that has been hidden or deleted?

Comment: @Tristan It's mentioned in the linked text (fourth line of the left column).

Comment: thanks, I hadn't clicked through before, and can't read the Hebrew regardless (so can't give tell the context)

Comment: "My garden has not been plowed of late."

Comment: Note that "vagina" itself is often used as a euphemism in English. Strictly speaking, the term refers to the internal part, while "vulva" refers to the externally visible features. (The same as calling one's belly a "stomach".)

Comment: @RayButterworth I don't think that's euphemism, just metonymy. And whilst it is true that in technical language the vagina is only the internal canal, from a descriptive POV it's clear that in informal speech the word refers to the vulva and vagina together

Answer (score 16):

This information is a bit difficult to find in the classic dictionaries, because they tend to be quite squeamish about explaining sexual things! But here's what Lewis and Short have to say about it.

> IIC: Like the Gr. κῆπος, i.q. pudendum muliebre, Poët. ap. Anth. Lat. I. p. 686 Burm.; also the posteriors of a boy, Auct. Priap. 5.

*Pudendum muliebre* is Latin for "that womanly thing you should be ashamed about", i.e. the genitals. So it seems that, indeed, both Latin *hortus* and Greek κῆπος can be used as euphemisms for the vagina. LSJ confirm this for κῆπος, which they define as "III. pudenda muliebria, D.L.2.116." (*Pudenda muliebria* is just the plural of *pudendum muliebre*.)

Lewis and Short say that it can also be used for a man's anus in a sexual sense, presumably transferred from the "vagina" meaning, but LSJ don't mention that for Greek, so that may be a metaphor that was only used in Latin (or maybe it was also used in Greek, just not often enough for LSJ to list it).

Comment: Is the answer yes or no?

Comment: @user1271772 does it need to be one or the other? Which it should be depends on where you draw the line between ad-hoc euphemistic metaphor and established sense, which different people can disagree with. Providing all the facts, as this answer does allows the reader to make that judgement themselves which is much more useful than a yes or no would be

Comment: @Tristan I disagree with you. While this answer is better than the other one, because it says what *Pudendum muliebre* means, it does not make the answer to the question clear.

Comment: @user1271772 The answer is yes: "both Latin hortus and Greek κῆπος can be used as euphemisms for the vagina".

Comment: @user1271772 Did you actually read the answer? It says quite plainly that the answer is yes. Answers don’t have to have a huge, bold ‘yes’ or ‘no’ at the top to be adequate answers to a question.

Comment: After the author's most recent comment I gave a +1 because the answer became a clear "yes". That comment wouldn't have been necessary or even sensible, if it was that clear in the original post.

Comment: @user1271772 I apologize if it didn't come across clearly. That comment was a quote from the original answer.

Comment: But not entirely.

Comment: @user1271772 Let's say Draconis stays in the tradition of the old linguists when he is  a bit circumspect in his wording ;-).

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it has been used in this way, and no, Kohut is not making it up. [Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dhortus) mention the relevant passages:

> C. Like the Gr. κῆπος, i. q. **pudendum muliebre**, Poët. ap. Anth. Lat. I. p. 686 Burm.; also the posteriors of a boy, Auct. Priap. 5.

You can probably guess which anatomical part is meant here. These 19th century dictionaries were often a bit shy, so they put vulgar sexual terms in Latin instead of English.

All the attestations, both in Latin here and [in Greek](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkh%3Dpos), so there's no saying when this metaphor developed, but it's probably only that, a metaphor and naught more. Similarly, Aristophanes uses [πεδίον](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0035%3Acard%3D86) as a metaphor for "the *pudenda muliebre*". There's nothing stopping writers from making those sort of metaphors, though that doesn't mean every writer would immediately make the connection, or that it exists in any and every passage.

Comment: Nathan Bailey, *An Universal Etymological English Dictionary, 8th ed.* London 1737, [p. 18](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_universal_etymological_English_dictio/VuYIAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA18-IA61&printsec=frontcover) 
" HORTUS [by some *Writers*] the privy Parts of a Woman. " Also, in Shakespeare's [Sonnet 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_16) one finds: " Now stand you on the top of happy hours, And many maiden gardens, yet unset, "

Comment: The dividing line between an established meaning and occasional metaphorical use is hard to draw even for current language.  Take e.g. “My anaconda don’t want none unless you got buns, hun.” The euphemistic intent of *anaconda* is clear, but only as a metaphor in context; in itself, we’d usually think of *anaconda* as just meaning the actual large reptile. On the other hand the euphemistic sense of *buns* is well-established enough that we’d expect a good dictionary to list it.  Shakespeare’s *maiden gardens* seems nearer the contextual-only end of this spectrum; where does *hortus* fall?

Comment: Is the answer yes or no?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine You can use almost any word as a euphemism for genitalia, it's the context that often makes it obvious. "Did you see that guy in his speedo? He obviously has a huge frog.":

Comment: @user1271772 does it need to be one or the other? Which it should be depends on where you draw the line between ad-hoc euphemistic metaphor and established sense, which different people can disagree with. Providing all the facts, as this answer does allows the reader to make that judgement themselves which is much more useful than a yes or no would be

Comment: @Tristan I disagree with you. This post does not answer the question in the title.

Comment: @user1271772 I thought the answer was understood from context, but hopefully my edit made it clearer.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine it is worth mentioning that there is a line in Plautus' Pseudolus where someone says: "When the soldier went on his watch at night and you went with him, did his sword fit in your scabbard?" and that is apparently the *only* evidence anywhere that the word *vagina* (scabbard) had a sexual meaning in pre-medieval Latin (and even then, the person this is addressed to appears to be male).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel That reminds me of [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/20762/what-where-the-formal-words-in-rome-for-human-genitals-i-have-heard-that-penis).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Interesting! I didn't know that!

Comment: @cmw thanks, the edit makes it a lot clearer!